# How to replace all continuous special characters with one underscore only

Tags: javascript, regex

How can we replace all special characters with `_`, provided if there are continuous special characters then they should be replaced with only one `_`. Example below.

| I/P. | O/P |
| --- | --- |
| abc@de# | abc_de_ |
| abc@.de | abc_de |

I am using `str.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '_')`, which works fine for non continuous characters.

Comment: Try adding a + at the end of your regex `str.replace(/[^\w\s]+/gi, '_')`.

Comment: @jkoch is there away I could avoid underscore at start and end as well?

Comment: Do you want to keep the special characters at the start and end or do you want to remove them?

Comment: I want to remove them

Comment: This could be done in a second step with replace. `str.replace(/[^\w\s]+/gi, '_').replace(/^_+|_+$/g,'')`